# systemctl Myservice.service not found

Tags: service, systemd, systemctl, rhel8

When I keep my `Myservice.service` file in `/etc/systemd/system/Myservice.service`. I get `not-found` error.

```
systemctl status Myservice
● Myservice.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: Unit Myservice.service not found.)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-08-27 11:04:58 EDT; 22min ago
 Main PID: 3539430 (code=exited, status=125)
```

But when I keep the same service file in `/lib/systemd/system/Myservice.service`. It  works fine.

But why doesn't it work in the first scenario? why systemd not able to find file in first case. How can I debug this scenario with systemd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, In RHEL 8, My Myservice.service default selinux context is `unconfined_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0` under /etc/systemd/system/, I changed it to `system_u:object_r:systemd_unit_file_t:s0`. and That's it!

Comment: For noobs like me: The command to do this is chcon system_u:object_r:systemd_unit_file_t:s0 [your-file]